# DWR and Jquery into spring MVC 2.5

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, dwr

From my shallow reading, Spring MVC does not support jquery directly.  It does enable integration with DWR framework.

From my understanding of DWR, it is an ajax framework that allows you to call javas methods from javascript.

Can I use both in my application?  With Jquery handling most of the javascript code and client side interaction and DWR making the ajax calls?

I am leaning towards learning jquery but there is no out of the box support for it in spring 2.5.

Comment: please check the below link for Implementation..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403846/how-to-use-dwrdirect-web-remoting-in-spring-mvc-4/31423283#31423283

Comment: please check the below link for Implementation..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403846/how-to-use-dwrdirect-web-remoting-in-spring-mvc-4/31423283#31423283

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  With spring you can use any type of view technology.  It is designed so that your view is decoupled from the service side code. And also you should use spring 3.0. And if you are using Jquery that has Ajax support built-in you don't really need to use DWR.  You can just have spring controller methods that handle specific URI templates. And have jquery hit those urls to make the ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answer but I found a very good blog for most of my questions about Spring MVC.

[This link](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-and-dwr-3-integration.html) provides a good tutorial how to integrates them.

Note that I had to use the DWR version 3.0.rc2 because there was problems with the upload control (input type=file) in the utils.js with the last stable version (2.0.8).

The release candidate (rc) was more stable for my project finally.